# How to update the ADF schedule time using the Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

This is my trigger typeProperties,

```
"type": "ScheduleTrigger",
        "typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Day",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2023-07-07T05:28:00",
                "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        10
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        16
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to change the hours 16 to 18 through the **azure cli**. I tried the multiple **update** statement but I couldn't able to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update schedule time using the Azure CLI You can use `az datafactory trigger update`  [Azure CLI command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/datafactory/trigger?view=azure-cli-latest#commands) with **--set** parameter specifying a property as path and value for updating an existing trigger.

```
az datafactory trigger update --resource-group "resourcegroup name" --factory-name "Datafactory name"  --name "Trigger name" --set properties.recurrence.schedule.minutes=[29]  --set properties.recurrence.schedule.hours=[29]
```

**Initial properties of my trigger:**

[image]

**After executing CLI command:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Pratik, this actually works for me. Appreciated !

Comment: hi @pratik I tried to update the weekdays of the trigger which is set to 7 weeks a day to only few days using  az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "***" --resource-group "**" --name "Daily_pipeline" 
--set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]

but it didn't gave the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @pratik every things goes well but when I use the same methodology to update the weekDays Value it fails to update,

```
"typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Week",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2023-01-23T032:00:00",
                "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "weekDays": [
                        "Monday",
                        "Tuesday",
                        "Wednesday",
                        "Thursday",
                        "Friday"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I treid this way:

```
az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "***" --resource-group "**" --name "Daily_pipeline" 
--set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]
```

it seValue it fails to properly instead it updates as a null,

Comment: Could you ask a new question in this platform, rather than posting it in answer?

Comment: @Aswin I asked the same question in the another thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76786172/how-to-update-the-adf-trigger-weekdays-parameter-using-the-azure-cli, could you plz answer it?