# How to Update the ADF trigger weekDays parameter using the azure cli?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-cli

My trigger is set for all 7 days a week but I want to update it for only fewdays using the **weekDays** parameter via **azure cli**

```
"typeProperties": {
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Week",
                "interval": 1,
                "startTime": "2023-01-23T032:00:00",
                "timeZone": "W. Europe Standard Time",
                "schedule": {
                    "minutes": [
                        0
                    ],
                    "hours": [
                        5
                    ],
                    "weekDays": [
                        "Monday",
                        "Tuesday",
                        "Wednesday",
                        "Thursday",
                        "Friday"
                    ]
                }
            }
```

I treid this way:

```
az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "...." --resource-group "...." --name "Daily_pipeline" 
--set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]
```

it seValue it fails to properly instead it updates as a null,

Answer (score 2):

Try enclosing the `weekDays` property value in single Quotes.

Below is the correct command:

```
az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "..." --resource-group "..." --name "trigger_name" --set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays='["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]'
```

**Trigger definition before update:**

[image]

**After update command**

[image]

Note: the `weekDays`  value needs to be enclosed in single quotes and the array of days needs to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: This works. Although, the JSON structure is odd. In ADF studio, the trigger json has weekdays property like this - properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays, whereas you don't have typeProperties in your command. Any idea if it is documented somewhere?
I kept passing weekdays as properties.typeProperties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"], without enclosing in string and it didn't work.

Comment: Yes, ADF studio' JSON format is different. If you list the trigger definition in bash, JSON didn't have `typeProperties`.I could not find any Microsoft document to explain this.

Comment: @Aswin This is not working for me at all, showing the error like  DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [str] an object of type <class 'str'>", 'Unable to deserialize response data. Data: \'["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]\', [str]', DeserializationError("Cannot deserialize as [str] an object of type <class 'str'>"))

Comment: Oh Okay.. Can you share the screenshot with the code?

Comment: Right. Well, thanks for the answer Aswin.

Comment: I used the same command @Aswin az datafactory trigger update --factory-name "..." --resource-group "..." --name "trigger_name" 
--set properties.recurrence.schedule.weekDays='["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday"]'

And received 
 DeserializationError: Cannot deserialize as [str] an object of type <class 'str'>", 'Unable to deserialize response data. Data: \'["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday"]\', [str]', DeserializationError("Cannot deserialize as [str] an object of type <class 'str'>"))